# Adding row to xml using lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I have a method which saves from reservations, but overwrites the output file every time when I create a new instance of `XmlReportGenerator`

```
from lxml import etree
from Flights.FlightTravelReservation import FlightTravelReservation

class XmlReportGenerator:
    root = None
    doc = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = etree.Element('results')
        self.doc = etree.ElementTree(self.root)

    def add_flight_row(self, flight_travel_reservation):
        page_element = etree.SubElement(self.root, 'FlightTravel')
        etree.SubElement(page_element, 'QuantityOfPassengers').text = 
             str(len(flight_travel_reservation.paxes))
        etree.SubElement(page_element,'Id').text = 
             flight_travel_reservation.reservation_id

    def Save(self, path = 'Flights.xml'):
        outFile = open(path, 'wb')
        self.doc.write(outFile)
```

Where sample output is:

```
<results>
  <FlightTravel>
    <Paxes>4</Paxes>
    <Id>259183</Id>
  </FlightTravel>
</results>
```

How do I modify add_flight_row method to add new rows? For example, I want something like:

```
<results>
  <FlightTravel>
    <Paxes>4</Paxes>
    <Id>259183</Id>
  </FlightTravel>
  <FlightTravel>
    <Paxes>9</Paxes>
    <Id>123456</Id>
  </FlightTravel>
</results>
```

I added test method:

```
def test_test(self,a,b):

    page_element = etree.SubElement(self.root,'FlightTravel')

    etree.SubElement(page_element,'QuantityOfPassengers').text = a
    etree.SubElement(page_element,'Id').text = b

    return page_element
```

And this is how I use it:

```
x=XmlReportGenerator()
x.test_test("a","b")
x.Save("test.xml")

x=XmlReportGenerator()
x.test_test("c","d")
x.Save("test.xml")
```

and in result I have:

```
<results>
  <FlightTravel>
    <Flights/>
    <QuantityOfPassengers>c</QuantityOfPassengers>
    <Id>d</Id>
  </FlightTravel>
</results>
```

instead of

```
<results>
  <FlightTravel>
    <Flights/>
    <QuantityOfPassengers>a</QuantityOfPassengers>
    <Id>b</Id>
  </FlightTravel>
  <FlightTravel>
    <Flights/>
    <QuantityOfPassengers>c</QuantityOfPassengers>
    <Id>d</Id>
  </FlightTravel>
</results>
```

Comment: You have not well-formed XML in both of your examples.

Comment: No, I can open it using IE so it's ok. There is a node flighs, but don't look at it. Now it is not important :)

Comment: Since you don't show code that calls `add_flight_row` I guess that you are `Save`ing every `results` tree for each element of `flight_travel_reservation` or are not looping at all. The code doesn't match the output, either, so please paste the actual code and output.

Comment: +1 thanks for clarifying the question. Every XML document has one and only one root. Therefore, if `Save` must generate a well-formed document it cannot simply concatenate today's `<results></results>` onto yesterday's. Thus phihag's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to define a `Load` function for XmlReportGenerator to load the old results.

```
class XmlReportGenerator(object):
    def __init__(self):
    # __init__, add_flight_row, and Save

    def load(self, path='Flights.xml'):
        try:
            self.doc = etree.ElementTree()
            self.root = self.doc.parse(path)
        except IOError:
            pass
```

and use it like this:

```
# day 1
x=XmlReportGenerator()
x.load('test.xml') # Silently catches the error if the file does not exit yet
x.test_test("a","b")
x.Save('test.xml')

# day2
x=XmlReportGenerator()
x.load('test.xml')
x.test_test("c","d")
x.Save("test.xml")
```

Comment: So I can't? I will be running this code everyday, so there is no chance to use the same instance of XmlReportGenerator

Comment: @user278618 I'm sorry, I didn't realize you wanted to append `cd` to the `ab` file, not just create the file with `abcd`.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `add_flight_row` (or `test_test`) repeatedly on the same instance for each row you want to add:

```
x = XmlReportGenerator()
x.test_test("a", "b")
x.test_test("c", "d")
x.Save("test.xml")
```

Comment: So I can't? I will be running this code everyday, so there is no chance to use the same instance of XmlReportGenerator